# HDMI Switch on Samsung monitor doesnt work

Tags: display, hdmi, switch

I have a samsung monitor model U28R55 ( https://displaysolutions.samsung.com/monitor/detail/1532/U28R55 )

I have a PS5 that I'd like to connect both to my monitor and to my TV, I've bought a Baseus HDMI switch and it doesnt work, the switch works with other old monitors but not with mine, i tried a few things and nothing worked:

-To switch to display port input on monitor

-To change the device from a PS5 to laptop or PC

-To switch HDMI cables

-To get another HDMI switch from another company

The monitor just blinks every few second and stays with a black screen.

Anyone knows how to fix it?

Comment: Which hdmi switch are you using?

Comment: the first one I've used was Baseus and the second one was [Vention](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32997268918.html?spm=a2g0s.9042311.0.0.72a94c4dCvscJz)

Comment: Could you put the links to them into your original question?